# How to create a Blackhole animation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Is that any Functionality Like Blackhole Animation like other cleaning app done.

The android built-in animations are very basic. I want something more fancy.

like: in the center of the screen a blackhole is created and some app icons are then going towards that blackhole.

Below is the sample App cleaner Animation that needed.
[image]

Comment: Get the app icons, render them with X/Y coordinates on a Canvas using a Thread, and plan a path for them to travel

Comment: can you share any code? or demo?

Comment: I can, but I have other things to do(I don't want to). Google "SurfaceView" and see in the SO Android documentation "Drawing to Canvas"

Comment: @LunarWatcher I am also very interested in animating Views. For instance, the StackOverflow app login screen. Do you just calculate a `Path` based on the screen size and then pass it after `animate()` ?

Comment: Possibly. Haven't had much to do with View-animations

Comment: Ok thanks for help